# What is the correct syntax for Sheets("sheet_1").ActiveCell.Offset(0, i + 1).Range("A1").Value

Tags: excel, vba

What is the correct syntax for telling VBA

"consider the value in sheet_1 in the cell that has offset (0,i) from the activecell" ?

I tried with

```
Sheets("sheet_1").ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Range("A1").Value
```

but it gives me

> runtime error 438

Please note that my aim is to do:

```
If Sheets("sheet_1").ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Range("A1").Value = Sheets("sheet_23").ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Range("A1").Value Then

'do something
```

Comment: Have you renamed your sheet to `sheet_1` with an underscore?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value`

Comment: @SJR I need the sheet dfinition in the same line, because I want to confront cells in different sheets at the same time

Comment: You can't have an active cell in more than one sheet.

Comment: but from the gui I can see the cursor in both sheets..

Comment: If you are planning on using `ActiveCell` you would need to `Activate` the relevant `Worksheet` (and potentially cell) before using it... it's recommended to avoid this if you can and I don't believe what you want is doable in your requirements...

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you're trying to achieve. You could extract the address of the active sheet on sheet1 and refer to the same cell on sheet2-  is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: @Samuel Everson yes, I renamed the sheet.

Comment: @SJR your comment "You can't have an active cell in more than one sheet." answers my question. Please type it as answer and I will flag it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActiveCell` is only the single active cell in whichever sheet is active at the time the code is run. It cannot refer to a cell on an inactive sheet. Another sheet must be activated first.

Of course you can use the `Address` property of an activecell and refer to the corresponding cell on an inactive sheet.

In general, it is [recommended not to use activecell or selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).